# Customize DropBox Login Screen

Tags: ios, dropbox, core-api

I am integrating DropBoxSDK Core API in my ios app. But when login screen appears the letter dropbox appears on my navigation Controller. After all day search on net also i am not able to find the solution. Please can anyone help me.

```
if (![[[DBSession sharedSession] userIds] containsObject:[[NSUserDefaults  standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"UID"]]) {

       [[DBSession sharedSession] linkFromController:self];
}
```

I am using above code to link it with my controller.

[image]

Comment: The letter are set by the Dropbox SDK, I'm guess you better not mess with it.

Comment: @rckoenes... but its not looking good. I tried to remove the image on navigation bar at that time but i am unable to do so for the login screen. it got removed from my viewcontroller screen.

Comment: Hey Shruti, how did you set the background image behind the words "Dropbox" on this navigationView?  That's something I'd like to do.

Comment: @yvanscher that image i set on my navigation bar.  In my whole app it was constant. So was coming in this page also.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought. I managed to get a reference to the dropbox login controller navigation item (I can print out the cancel button and the dropbox title set by dropbox sdk) but I don't seem to be able to make any changes to it (like setting my own title / titleView on the dropbox view).

Comment: @yvanscher yes you cannot set the title to that. i also struggled through the same to have a custom title but i did not find any solution.

Comment: Alright thanks anyways.